# how to return one object from inner join Linq to Sql expression method?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I use inner join to get compteurs of a membre using Linq to Sql expression method, but I don't know how to return only compteurs objects from results.

```
public List<EntityCompteur> GetMembreCompteurs(int membreId)
{
     return _entities.EntityCompteurs
        .Join(
            _entities.Contrat.Where(u => u.MembreId == membreId),
            compteur => compteur.CompteurId,
            utilisatuer => utilisatuer.CompteurId,
            (compteur, utilisatuer) => 
            // I want to return only compteur;
        ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Just put in `=> compteur`.

Comment: Thanks, that works I did not notice that.

Comment: Another node for that: the .Select(...) is handy on a more general view on this problem.